# H2 - Database is already closed

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm trying to use the H2 database in a Spring Boot project. When I run a project, a database error pops up:

> Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM
>   shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"; to the db URL)
>   [90121-199]

When I add: ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"; this url also closes but without warning. What could be the problem?

application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/database
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Maven pom:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

If you still need it, for me the that problem was resolved adding the reference to module web of Spring in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That dependency needs to be added.

Comment: yes, otherwise the database will close instantly, I also did the same mistake, I added the jar using the FIX PROJECT Setup option but didn't add it to pom.xml, thus faced the same issue.

Comment: Thanks that did it for me. I wonder why is this not mentioned on h2 configuration for spring.

Answer (score 1):

add the below line in application.property file

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true